# 2005 PT Cruiser Turbo check engine light

Tags: engine, cel, chrysler, pt-cruiser

My check engine light has been on. I had it checked by my mechanic and was told no codes showed up. This morning the check engine light started blinking.

Comment: If there is a check engine light, the car should have set some codes

Answer (score 1):

Shut the car off!  A **blinking** check engine light can quickly destroy an engine.  Possible causes include leaking fuel injector, broken ignition coil/wire/spark plug.

Answer (score 0):

If the car is working perfectly fine. Could it be that you did not tighten the gas cap when you refilled? It looks like this is a very common problem. You may even need a new gas cap.

See this for more info:
[Check engine light is on, but no codes?](http://www.ptcruiserlinks.com/forum/tech-performance-forum/30024-check-engine-light-but-no-codes.html)

I would go to a different mechanic next time. :)